# Возможно ли увеличить fps демонстрации экрана в браузере?

Tags: javascript, mediastream

Для получения потока с демонстрацией экрана я использую `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia`, всё работает, но видео имеет всего 3-5 фпс (оценивал на глаз). Смотреть на это не очень комфортно, можно ли как-то увеличить fps этого видео?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints/frameRate, это решает мою проблему

Для того, чтобы сказать браузеру сколько кадров вы хотите получить необходимо при создании объекта `mediaStream` передать в конструктор словарь с соответствующими свойствами. За fps отвечает свойство frameRate.

Например:

```
let desktop = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, frameRate: 60});
```

Comment: Спасибо. убрал свои, более не актуальные, комментарии